# Android - String resource value in string.xml can't be changed

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to change the value of the following string resource from :

`<string name="waitlist_closed">Waitlist closed</string>`

to

`<string name="waitlist_closed">test</string>`

I update a TextView text value with this line :
`statusText?.text = context.getString(R.string.waitlist_closed)`

But I keep seeing this result when I launch the app, the TextView shows "Waitlist closed" instead of "test". [Here is a screenshot of what is shown on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGqpH.png)

I tried to wipe data of the emulator, invalidates cache of android studio, restart it but the problem still occurs.

If I set the TextView text to another string resource it works just fine, I am trying to understand why when I'm using waitlist_closed string resource it always displays "Waitlist closed" with whatever value I set

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Do you have only one language configuration? It could be that you are updating the value in strings.fr but your device language is English so your text is using value from strings.en that is still not updated

Comment: Mikhail found the answer, the app is choosing strings according to a language configuration and I believe that's why I can't just update a string resource if it exists in the language configuration
Thank you Mikhail :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's happen.

1, Clean project

2, Invalidate & cache restart

3, Sync project with gradles

Now you can run....